# Xcode 9: Swift dependency analysis error

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xcode9-beta

I have an iOS-app written in obj-C and UI-tests for the app in Swift. I recently installed Xcode 9 beta 2 and wanted to compile the app. I get the following error:

*"Dependency Analysis Error > The “Swift Language Version” (SWIFT_VERSION) build setting must be set to a supported value for targets which use Swift. This setting can be set in the build settings editor."*

[image: Screenshot added]

When I go to build settings there isn't any possibility to set a version for Swift language. Does this represent a bug? Furthermore the app itself doesn't use Swift, only the automated UI_tests.

Comment: Double check the Code Generation option of Core Data Model, if the new Model has been created.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It tells that you need to specify the swift version in Build Settings. Just click project and go to Build settings (not the target) and set **"Swift Language Version"** to **Swift 3.2** or **Swift 4**. Here you have an screenshot :)

[image]

Comment: thanks for responding, but the UI-test target is actually the only one where I can set the swift language version. all other build setting sheets do not contain this option. although I'm not even trying to start the tests, just the app.

Comment: Then just only in the UI-Test target if you only have Swift in there.

Comment: Tried both versions 3.2 and 4.0 but nothing changes :/

Comment: It worked after restarting and cleaning the project, but maybe this will help someone else

Answer (score -1):

First of all I would ***recommend you to use stable version of Xcode since beta may contain bugs.***
Xcode 9.2 version is available. You can download XIP file from this [link](https://developer.apple.com/services-account/download?path=/Developer_Tools/Xcode_9.2/Xcode_9.2.xip).

You can resolve this error by using below steps :

1. Select **PROJECT**
2. Select **Build Settings**
3. In **Swift Language Version** section select `Swift 3.2` or `Swift 4.0` depending on your requirement.
4. Repeat same steps for **TARGETS** as well
5. Now **clean** the project (shortcut : `cmd + shift + k`)
6. Now this should `build without an error`

[image: Screenshot 1]

If you still get the same error then use below steps :

1. **Quit Xcode** (shortcut : `cmd + Q`)
2. Open your project
3. **Clean project** (shortcut : `cmd + shift + k`)